# How to create a new java.io.File in memory?

Tags: java, file, java-io

How can I create new `File` (from `java.io`) in memory, not on the hard disk?

I am using the Java language. I don't want to save the file on the hard drive.

I'm faced with a bad API (`java.util.jar.JarFile`). It's expecting `File file` of `String filename`. I have no file (only `byte[]` content) and can create temporary file, but it's not beautiful solution. I need to validate the digest of a signed jar.

```
byte[] content = getContent();
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".tmp");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(archiveContent);
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(tempFile);
Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
```

Any examples of how to achieve getting manifest without creating a temporary file would be appreciated.

Comment: So you just want bytes in memory?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with this `File`?

Comment: A `File` by definition is on the hard drive.

Comment: what's the point of creating a file if you don't want it on persistent memory?

Comment: @UwePlonus no... `new File("/dev/null")`

Comment: @fge `/dev/null` is on the hard drive (even if it is only a device ;)

Comment: has nothing to do with java, but maybe you want a ramdisk? Though i can hardly believe what you are trying to do really needs that...

Comment: @UwePlonus Unless you use a [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) or a [`Ram Drive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)

Comment: @UwePlonus erm, no... Not with modern Linux systems at least (this is a tmpfs)

Comment: I just want to save some stream in memory.

Comment: A stream of what? How large?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "save" that stream in memory?  If you have Java objects to work with, then the data is already in memory...

Comment: @UwePlonus No, /dev/null isn't anywhere, let alone on the hard disk. It is just a perfect sink and a source of endless EOFs, implemented in software only.

Comment: Similarly, it would be magical if there was a solution (although I know that there is not). I need to interact with an API that expects a File, but I'm interacting from a Google Appengine app, and we all know what GAE thinks of creating Files (hint: it hates it and it's granny)

Comment: Wow, the lack of imagination on StackOverflow is astounding. Someone might need an in-memory File simple because they are using an interface that requires a File. The interface should have been written for an InputStream, but it wasn't. A temp file just seems like overkill, so an in-memory java.io.File would be preferable.

Comment: You are not 'faced with a bad API' at all. It's just that this is the only one you've found so far. Have a look at `java.util.jar.JarInputStream`. There is nothing about this problem that requires the contradiction in terms you have dreamed up.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is not possible to create a `java.io.File` that holds its content in (Java heap) memory *.

Instead, normally you would use a stream. To write to a stream, in memory, use:

```
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out.write(...);
```

But unfortunately, a stream can't be used as input for `java.util.jar.JarFile`, which as you mention can only use a `File` or a `String` containing the path to a valid JAR *file*. I believe using a temporary file like you currently do is the only option, unless you want to use a different API.

If you are okay using a different API, there is conveniently a class in the same package, named `JarInputStream` you can use. Simply wrap your `archiveContent` array in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, to read the contents of the JAR and extract the manifest:

```
byte[] content = getContent(); // from OP's code

try (JarInputStream stream = new JarInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content))) {
     Manifest manifest = stream.getManifest();
}
```

---

*) It's obviously possible to create a full file-system that resides in memory, like a RAM-disk, but that would still be "on disk" (and not in Java heap memory) as far as the Java process is concerned.

Comment: This does not answer the question since ByteArrayOutputStream is not usable with an interface that requires a file object.

Comment: @FableBlaze Well, the answer to the question then, is “it’s not possible”. This answer tries to be pragmatic and tell what the user could do instead. Andreas’ answer is clearly more thorough and a better (attempt at an) answer.

Comment: "It's not possible" would be a valid answer in my opinion. However i think that an in-memory filesystem (mentioned in the comments of Andreas’ answer) could also be mentioned, because if you cant for some reason write to the hard-drive, then that could be a way around it.

Answer (score 98):

> How can I create new File (from java.io) in memory , not in the hard disk?

Maybe you are confusing `File` and `Stream`:

- A [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is an abstract representation of file and directory **pathnames**. Using a `File` object, you can access the file metadata in a file system, and perform some operations on files on this filesystem, like delete or create the file. But the `File` class does not provide methods to read and write the file contents.
- To read and write from a file, you are using a `Stream` object, like [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) or [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). These streams can be created from a `File` object and then be used to read from and write to the file.

You can create a **stream based on a byte buffer which resides in memory**, by using a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) and a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to read from and write to a **byte buffer** in a similar way you read and write from a file. The `byte` array contains the "File's" content. You do not need a `File` object then.

Both the `File...` and the `ByteArray...` streams inherit from `java.io.OutputStream` and `java.io.InputStream`, respectively, so that you can use the common superclass to hide whether you are reading from a file or from a byte array.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what the original poster wanted, but one example when a "File in memory" would be useful is when you want to reuse an existing library which needs a java.io.File as an input parameter, but you actually want to use "files" stored in memory. In that case, I think that one solution would be to use Apache Commons VFS to instantiate a DefaultFileSystemManager and use it to create a RamFileProvider. I would have added this as a (more complete) proper answer, but it seems that this question has been closed some time ago...

Comment: +1  I was looking for this kind of solution, to unit test come component without having to use an actual file

Comment: If you don't want to create "an actual file" then you can try creating a temporary file. See `createTempFile` for `java.io.file`. This file can be set to auto delete when unit test exits.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As @SorinPostelnicu well said a "File" in memory is something like a Filesystem in memory or so.

Comment: Probably sums the OP's use case and a valuable method of reducing latency with expensive system disk i/o.

Comment: OP is definitely NOT confusing files and streams. He thinks he wants to use jarFile to read a file and all he has is thebytes from some source (getContent()).

Comment: Good explanation, which should be preferred in which case?

Comment: @AshishLohia It depends - a `File` is the "name" of a file (its location), while a `Stream` is the data in the file. If you want to access the data in a file, you need a `Stream` (you can create `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` from a `File` by passing the file to their constructors). If you want to handle file names and directories you use `File` (Note that since Java 7, there is also a `Paths` and `Files` class in the `java.nio.file` package)

Comment: Thanks Andreas, do we also need to consider the size of the data as well while choosing? Or it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 13):

You could use an in-memory filesystem, such as [Jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs)

Here's a usage example from their readme:

```
FileSystem fs = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());
Path foo = fs.getPath("/foo");
Files.createDirectory(foo);

Path hello = foo.resolve("hello.txt"); // /foo/hello.txt
Files.write(hello, ImmutableList.of("hello world"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Jimfs does not support `File` object

Answer (score 5):

I think temporary file can be another solution for that.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(byteArray);
```

There is a an answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006461/create-a-temporary-java-io-file-from-byte).

Comment: The OP wanted to create the file in memory and not to disk.

Comment: @Hephaestus: Right, but that's not really doable, so this is the best alternative.

Comment: Not true.  Our server code generates hundreds of files per second in memory for writing to S3.  Putting this to disk first would a major bottleneck.  Just use an InputStream as mentioned above.  This is very doable.