# Create a temporary java.io.File from byte[]

Tags: java, file, arrays

I must use an existing method that is like `saveAttachment(Attachment attachment)` where `Attachment` has a `File attribute`.

My problem is that I'm retrieving a `byte[]` and I want to save it using this method. How can I have a "local" `File` just for saving ?

Sorry if my question is dumb, I don't know much about Files in Java.

Comment: From where you are retreiving byte[]? Where you want to save your data? Need more context & explanation

Comment: I save the data using a method that itself uses alfresco community sdk to store the file, so I can't change the way it is saved. And I retrieve the byte from a web-service that does not provide other information. For those reasons I didn't give more details in my question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(byteArray);
```

Check out related docs:

[File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, directory);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 5):

Reading All Bytes or Lines from a File

```
Path file = ...;
byte[] fileArray;
fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(file);
```

Writing All Bytes or Lines to a File

```
Path file = ...;
byte[] buf = ...;
Files.write(file, buf);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck.

```
File.createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)
```

Creates a file in the default temp directory of the OS, where it's guaranteed you can write to.